# Strange R random component

Tags: r, dataset

I'm relatively new to R so maybe I'm missing something but by my own I cannot figure it out.

I've this data-set: [DOWNLOAD .TXT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/upvzzwdjdbgsujz/DistrBdaily.txt?dl=0) that contains sales data aggregated by week (51 weeks for 2 years leading to 102 entries).

This is the code I use to transform data in a *timeserie*, plot and then decompose in the main components

```
# creating a timeseries element, frequency sets the intervals of data collection, starts sets the data collection date
timeseries = ts(data, frequency = 51, start = c(2011))
plot.ts(timeseries, type = "o")

#TimeSeries decomposition in trend, seasonal and random-walk
plot(decompose(timeseries))
```

The result is a decompose figure very strange, especially for the random part.

[image: Decompose]

These are my qustions:

1. Why the charts starts at 2011.5 when the data starts 2011.1?
2. Why the random component is so strange?

What I'm missing?

Comment: For me your code worked fine and the result looks good. Maybe you did something wrong while loading the data.

Comment: Note: In your `ts()` function call you have the frequency set to "12" whereas it sounds like you're dealing with weekly data.

Comment: Both of you are right, I paste the wrong image and i didn't check the code. If i chose the right frequency number (51 in this case) i get a strange simil "step" random chart. @holzben If you use my code, did you get my figure? if now how do you load the data?

Comment: My guess is that the problem is a result of you only having two years of data. For instance, notice how if you change the time series to monthly data and then plot the result the problem goes away.

Comment: Indeed you are right! So i think the only viable way is to try to obtain more data :(

Comment: @gmeroni No, i got a figure where the random component looks fine.

Comment: @holzben this is very strange...did you used frequency 12 or 51?

Comment: I used ``read.delim`` for reading the data and afterwards your code ``timeseries = ts(data, frequency = 12, start = c(2011))``

Comment: @holzben Ok, i think that if you change freq. to 51 you'll get my result. Since that are weekly data i should use 52.